# Bitline is not working correctly (6t cell sram with sense amp and precharge)

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, memory, pspice, sram

After simulating 6t ram with sense amplifier and precharge, bit line value is fixed to 1.5v. How can i avoid this? Using pspice to simulate.

[image: Circuit Graph]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two things. Simulators are very good at finding metastable states that could never persist in real life because of component tolerances and thermal noise. I think that's what you've got here. But another thing is that you're using 3-terminal transistors that have their substrates tied to their sources. If you're going to design circuits like these (i.e., integrated circuits), you need to use 4-terminal devices with their substrates tied directly to the supply rails -- N-channel to the negative rail and P-channel to the positive rail.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Statement:

When the Write Level, (WL) FETs have the same RdOn as the Cell FETs they cannot guarantee a change in level so they operate in linear saturation mode at Vdd/2 somewhat like a CD4xxx inverter FET with a negative feedback resistor. The WL NFETs "MUST HAVE" a lower resistance when active than either Cell PFET which is high.

The problem with this design simulation may be a lack of design specs.

The function of the WL, WL! FETs in Q192, Q193 is to overpower the cell logic states with the Bit Lines FETs using KVL and the response of the FET currents with Id=(Vgs-Vt)²*beta for each FET.

Essentially the dynamic RdsOn of the Write Bit Lines must be lower than the cell dynamic RdsOn after a power-on-reset, POR.  Reducing RdsOn of any FET by geometry normally adds Coss capacitance and slows down the memory, so preferably increase (Vgs-Vt)² by at least a factor of 4 with 2x difference by lowering Vt.

Keep in mind Vt tolerance in production is +/-50% (hint: Vgs(th) read specs). The design specs should define the **Static Noise Margin, SNM** to gate threshold over all Vdd range and variation of Vgs(th) = Vt with temperature and production process controls.

This SNM spec is a key Figure of Merit, FoM along with the dynamic pulse duration, delay specs to achieve minimum write times or max. read speeds in GHz for Static RAM, SRAM.

**The SNM is equivalent to a large linear diff. amp offset voltage during Write which affects the output to gate threshold transfer function.**

Your next challenge then is to use RdsOn FETs with very low Coss with low subthreshold voltages, Vt (aka Vgs(th)), say 0.5V and a 1 to 1.5V Vdd supply. But the Write FETs must be sufficiently lower RdsOn to perform the reset to Q or Qbar (aka Q!)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSGMeO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The BL FETs will reset the cell memory when both cell inputs have crossed their thresholds to assert the inverter output.

I chose [Cell FETs in my simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CMAWEBOAbAOgOw8gZjUkgA5E0s00piQ8oIYF4AoAJSgCYbEbIuR4VCBEQQ6w8BkjMAZlETIkySCg4CFtNfCmSwHWVHhaNZRRrxadYDHoOQjIYiLTIntOtsi79cyBrcqam54HlY2%20gDuIKaoVDHwDpHRLgIO8fxgzFGBqWo5RjSZ2aqxUCUJakn2QQwO6OBZhmr11erIRfKuDBoFDdk9-H5m7Y35Dq31HfHjA4WNMSkxPH3JyMt83HPFaik5yx17vPz78ymCzooUK-FXrfBXB%20VoDOUPo69UQwJvUaIQ9QQaPUkoQqPVyM0qPoAOacGj3T78eAlYTMADGcLamIR4AEcESGBQRKQ5BQWA4eHgYDwKC81jAYBYGI20SONDcEHg%20MqhNUiCwjKpaA4HDAQhsjNGPVuSJ%20TW%20iPhb1FWDKWkGV16yAAigAjACGACdmCqQCLkOaBCVLTqTWBVeluBYBMcQNrmABJM0cC0%20s3k73tM06PDMQSVAOWiwQS1qAAm0Bk%20oArgAbAAusFT0DjAjzwhsLFheD4gdopZ9Ekyhs0Mb9Jcqfs5DIMiEErOi7fq9U8ukQBhcIhog9KPbCYH7vxS9UQzsm70hIGFyHnsLbYLi7YquMysJH4NEuR3jRHyxHqKi587Qmu7ZE7ZOvzvtDQhQaAA8l2dRUviPCKdEAhUAAQgAMgAhJ6IDkv8VAQqUMYhnaqqAqUqGLCAYHIdBBClFguEYVhUQwXhuHzp%20lICCWAjECgVHcEBIAACoAPbQtC2YADoAM7ptAvE8cBACW6Y8aBQkAHbQDxnEAI4AHzYRwkAbrQE6lMgWGmqhYi4SIIAAOqgY0opAlCKmlPoprKTeXBvsgRkmRZMZgG%20%20g1tG-pqA2Xm4lSu7lhG3kVn%20x7hr5HABp5kWVCACZJmmmbZrm8A7roLBerGkbZWoiFeKG1l%20jFVpBYBepGswn7wAx8CQKqDqMQACmm3HSdxBmGiJbXiVJMkKSZrmWYNSgrMVsbDRomTsKZfkPLiWgMotS0CDovYFngWCjPwAT%20Be2IaHck2VbQ1rKdBP4ijVahMQAFvxbUALYsQmqbcTxN36gAbm1YE8Ya93pm93ERCJN08awcbcQA8hJck8ZAYAAKQ8SxMg8Wi0CpqmPG6iJQPMCxX4uvZYAoLwkipZyBPqMTflcHowZEkSxBYAo6B4MQzx0fSDKU2aVENBzRMAGKpXSAgMiACAgAAIsm6YAJ48QAwgraLZswQA) of Beta=40m with Vt=1.5V and WR FETs with Beta=20m and Vt=20m. This controls Id and RdsOn = Vdd/Id when Vgs=Vdd.

### Solution

It is not a metastable problem, rather it's an analog threshold problem with equal dynamic resistive ratios and effective capacitance  Ciss, Coss flip-flop delays to achieve a stable toggled, latched memory-state during Write.

Note: I only used 4 pad FETS for WL, but more changes may be considered. In Falstad Sim. , FET > edit,  uncheck "Body Terminal".

My solution is just for educational purpose and not optimal. It does show however that even an ideal Falstad simulator can demonstrate the solution with better timing diagrams without the need to define every part.  But you do have control over Vt and beta on FETs.

### Potential Solutions to WL write a "0" when PFET="1"

- asymmetric higher RdsOn on cell FET vs Nch RdsOn WL FET
- reduce Vt towards 0.5V to achieve a much lower RdsOn with WL FETs.
- decrease RdsOn in WL FETs to increase "beta" in WL (x2 as in my sim.)

I used a circuit to display logic levels with LEDs and then fed back Qbar to BL ( like D in a flip flop) to make a divide by 2 counter from memory to test max. speed.

A clever observer will see a slider for the 1 GHz WL clock duty cycle and with a very low cell capacitance of 1 pF total, there is a threshold where memory begins to fail. ( in my hypothetical Sim. solution)

**For 25 bonus points, ;) what is that error-free threshold?**